# Pre-Authorization in Payeezy API

Tags: php, api, payment-gateway, firstdata, payeezy

I have been trying to pre-authorize payments using **Payeezy** gateway, but doesn't seem to work. 
Tried with API references, but couldn't locate the token in my response to use further!. 
Any help regards Payeezy pre-authorization flow? Thanks in advance!

```
<form action="https://demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/pay" method="POST" name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input name="x_login" value="XXX" type="hidden">
<input name="x_amount" value="0" type="hidden">
<input name="x_fp_sequence" value="FP_SEQUENCE" type="hidden">
<input name="x_fp_timestamp" value="FP_TIMESTAMP" type="hidden">
<input name="x_fp_hash" value="FP_HASH" size="50" type="hidden">
<input name="x_currency_code" value="FP_HASH" type="hidden">
<input name="x_gateway_id" value="GATEWAY_ID" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="x_show_form" value="PAYMENT_FORM"/>
<input name="x_type" value="AUTH_ONLY" type="hidden">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your work please ?

Comment: @Pogrindis: I have attached the form in my question.